# Create a new menu item in eclipse UI

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a need to create a new dropdown menu visible in the eclipse UI beside the numerous items that already exist in the eclipse menu i.e starting from `new` to `save` command to `debug` items etc . ( The entire row of items below the File , Edit ,Navigate,etc toolbar )

How is that possible ? Will this new added menu item also be a plugin . Can someone suggest a good tutorial as a starting point of learning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands can be implemented using org.eclipse.ui.handlers and bound to keys using org.eclipse.ui.bindings.  This is helpful for you.

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_menus.htm

Answer (score 1):

there are great number of eclipse plugin tutorials available ,
eclipse works as an integration of plugins (everything in eclipse is a plugin)

you can start by

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Ffirstplugin.htm

search the web,its prity easy.

Cheers.!!